# Is there any way to change chrome settings without opening a new browser in Selenium with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome

I'm trying to make a selenium project and I wonder if there is a way to change browser settings without opening a new browser. For example I want to open up a browser with some proxy connection, after that I want to change the proxy server of that browser. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. You can use ChromeOptions. Check [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities) for more info.